# (JAVA) I need help creating a class with getters and setters, creating a class with an array and then calling upon the other class.

Tags: java, arrays

This is my objective--
you have to create 2 classes:
 1. Student class
      Attributes
Create a Student class with 3 attributes(instance variables), including
◦     name (String)
◦     midterm (double)
◦     finalExam (double)
 Methods
Define setters/getters for each attributes. Therefore, you have to create 3 setters and 3 getters in total.
In the setters of midterm and finalExam, you have to check whether the given grade is valid. The grade has to be between 0-100. If it is invalid, print out an error message “The grade is invalid!”
Define a method, getFinalGrade, which calculates the final grade according to the following grading scheme. After the computation, return the result of final grade.
◦     Grading:
▪     Midterm:        40%
▪     Final exam:    60%
Define a method, showGrades, which outputs the details of attributes. The grades should be displayed as a number with two decimal places only. (See the example)
◦     Output example: “Name: Tom, Midterm: 90.00, Final Exam: 80.00, Final Grade: 82.00”

1. GradeCalculator class
   Create a GradeCalculator class and put everything (Step 1 to Step 4) in the main method.
   Step 1: create a Student array, called studentArray, whose length is 5.
   Step 2: create 5 Student objects by using loop. Ask the user to input name, midterm, final exam one at a time (prompt the user) and store these in corresponding attributes by calling the appropriate setters. After all values are set, store the newly-created Student object to studentArray.
   Step 3: loop studentArray to print out the details of each student by calling showGrades.
   Step 4: calculate the average final grade of these 5 student and print it out on the screen. The grades should be displayed as a number with two decimal places only.

Here is the code I have written thus far:

```
public class Student {

private String name;
private double midterm;
private double finalExam;
private double finalGrade;

public Student(String n, double a, double m)
{
    name = n;
    midterm = a;
    finalExam = m;
}


public String getName()
{
    return (name);
}
public double getmidterm()
{
    return (midterm);
}

if (midterm < 0)
{
midterm = 0;
System.out.println("The grade is invalid! Grade will be entered as 0.");
}
if (midterm >100)
{
midterm = 100;
System.out.println("The grade is invalid! Grade will be entered as 100.");
}
else
{
System.out.println("Midterm grade recorded." + midterm);
}
public double getfinalExam()
{
    return (finalExam);
}

if (finalExam < 0)
{
    finalExam = 0;
    System.out.println("The grade is invalid");
}
if (finalExam > 100)
{
    finalExam = 100;}
    System.out.println("The grade is invalid! Grade will be entered as 100.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Final Exam grade recorded." + finalExam);
}
public double getfinalGrade()
{
finalGrade = (midterm * .40) + (finalExam * .60);
    return (finalGrade);
}
public double showGrades()
{
System.out.println("Name:" + name + "midterm:" + midterm + "Final Exam:"  + finalExam);
}
public void setName(String studentName) 
{
    name = studentName;
}
public void setMidterm(double midtermGrade)
{
    midtermGrade = midterm;
}
public void setFinal(double finalGrade)
{
    finalGrade = finalExam;
}
```

Code:

```
public class GradeStudents{
Student[] students;
import java.util.Scanner;

GradeStudents(){}

public static void main(String[] args)  {

String[] studentarr = new String[5];

for(double i = 0; i < 5; i++);
    { //insert what the for loop executes here}
}


}

}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your specific problem doing that? Did it work?

Comment: This is not a place to have your homework made.

Comment: My specific problem is that I am not sure how to write the controlling for loop in the GradeStudents class. I am also unsure if the Student class' getters and setters are correct. This is not a homework assignment. It is me attempting to learn to program Java via completing specific objectives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this meet your question?

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

Student[] studentarr = new Student[5];

for(double i = 0; i < 5; i++);
{ 
   studentarr[i] = new Student(params...);
}

studentarr[0].someStudentMethod();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go is i think is to populate some arrays with data and run the code to see if you get output or errors.

Where does the student data come from? Through userinterface input or from a text,xml or json file?

Comment: The student data is supposed to come from user interface input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an If statement outside a method therefore potentially the program will throw back errors / exceptions at you.

Just a snippet of this code

```
public double getmidterm()
{
    return (midterm);
}
// Potentially an error here
if (midterm < 0)
{
midterm = 0;
System.out.println("The grade is invalid! Grade will be entered as 0.");
}
```

You might want to put these if statements in a method and call this method in your test class (main method).

Also, You are defining get and set methods however they are not returning values (in this case):

```
public double showGrades()
{
System.out.println("Name:" + name + "midterm:" + midterm + "Final Exam:"  + finalExam);
}
```

Here you should be returning a double not a println to the console.

If you have a toString method which gives back the student, you should be able in your loop to call student.toString() and it will display the values you want.